# Проверка наличие лишних файлов скриптом bash

Tags: bash

Приветствую всех. Мои познания в bash очень невелики, но нужно очень разрешить такую задачу.

Есть файл со списком файлов.

Пример:

```
/tmp/my/file1.txt
/tmp/my/file2.txt
```

Как сделать так, чтобы при проверке на наличие файла в папке /tmp/my/ из списка необходимых файлов, мне приходили ответы:

1 - Файлы найдены:

```
/tmp/my/file1.txt
/tmp/my/file2.txt
```

2 - В папке /tmp/my/ есть файлы и папке не включенные в список:

```
/tmp/my/test
/tmp/my/1.txt
```

Comment: Слить листинг в другой файл, и потом пройти по нему дважды поиском имён (поштучным) из первого файла (на первом проходе выводить найденные, на втором отсутствующие). Например...

Answer (score 6):

например, так:

1. файлы найдены:

   ```
   $ comm -1 -2 <(sort /ваш/файл/со/списком) <(find /tmp/my -print | sort)
   ```
2. есть файлы/каталоги, не включенные в список:

   ```
   $ comm -1 -3 <(sort /ваш/файл/со/списком) <(find /tmp/my -mindepth 1 -print | sort)
   ```

правда, с программой *bash* используемые здесь программы не имеют никакой связи помимо того, что все они входят в состав операционной системы *gnu*.

---

**пояснение**

конструкция `<(команда)` — это [подстановка процесса](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_substitution). доступна она, как написано в приведённой ссылке, в оболочках *korn* и *bash*. в оболочке *zsh* немного другой синтаксис: [`=(команда)`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Intro/intro_7.html)

с помощью этой конструкции при вызове программы, принимающей в качестве параметра файл(ы), можно подменить этот файл содержимым *stdout* указанной команды.

Comment: Разве конструкция `<(...)` это не *bash*? (заодно рассказали бы о ней поподробней в своем ответе, подозреваю ТС и куча др. читателей плохо представляют как это работает)

Comment: @avp, если каждую буквочку сопровождать [пояснениями](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_substitution), эдак википедия получится вместо so.

Comment: Ну, хоть намекните ссылочкой в ответе, что в команду вместо `<(...)` будет передаваться имя "файла" (на самом деле FIFO) с выводом команды в скобках.

Comment: не имя а дескриптор

Comment: -sh: syntax error: unexpected "("

Comment: @mulrus, так используйте *bash*, а не *sh*.

Comment: @mulrus, Shell -- трудный язык, поэтому существуют проблемы переносимости.